# Unable to convert string to JSON object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Below is Json string

```
{
  "Resources": {
    "Resource": [
      {
        "ResourceId": "D513E96F-EA6C-E511-8133-000D3A0044F4",
        "MSPSLogin": "richa.dinesh.parkar",
        "Email": "richa.dinesh.parkar@accenture.com"
      },
      {
        "ResourceId": "D513E96F-EA6C-E511-8133-000D3A0044F4",
        "MSPSLogin": "harshal.arun.vadnere",
        "Email ": "harshal.arun.vadnere@accenture.com"
      }
    ]
  },
    "CreatedOn":"2016-07-18T12:51:14.23Z",                         
    "CreatedByApp":"AD"                           
}
```

My class in Models:

```
public class Resource   
{
    public string ResourceId { get; set; }
    public string MSPSLogin { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

}

public class Resources
{
    public IList<Resource> Resource { get; set; }
}

public class Example
{
    public Resources Resources { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string CreatedByApp { get; set; }
}
```

I use Json.Net, I want to convert string below to Json Object.

```
Example example = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Example>(jsonstr);
```

But it error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[myWizard_MSPS_integration.Example]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: [Your code seems to work fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d8VuSX) when I try it.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing `IList<Resource>` to `IEnumerable<Resource>` or `Resource[]`, I think Json.Net cannot initialize `IList`. Not supported feature.

Answer (score 3):

Just change the type of `Resources` property to `IEnumerable<Resource>`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this class model:

```
public class Resource
{
    public string ResourceId { get; set; }
    public string MSPSLogin { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class Resources
{
    public List<Resource> Resource { get; set; }
}

public class Example
{
    public Resources Resources { get; set; }
    public string CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string CreatedByApp { get; set; }
}
```

Replace

```
    public IList<Resource> Resource { get; set; }
```

With

```
    public List<Resource> Resource { get; set; }
```